# I am unable to run this python file list.py from cs50w

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

this is my source code:

```
import os

from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker

engine = create_engine("postgresql://postgres:12345@localhost:5432/postgres")
db = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))

def main():
    flights = db.execute("SELECT origin, destination, duration FROM flights").fetchall()
    for flight in flights:
        print(f"{flight.origin} to {flight.destination}, {flight.duration} minutes.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

this is the error that showing when i am trying to run this program :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "list.py", line 6, in <module>
    engine = create_engine("postgresql://postgres:12345@localhost:5432/postgres")
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\__init__.py", line 479, in create_engine
    return strategy.create(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\strategies.py", line 87, in create
    dbapi = dialect_cls.dbapi(**dbapi_args)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\dialects\postgresql\psycopg2.py", line 737, in dbapi
    import psycopg2
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'psycopg2'
```

I am sure I have used the database name , username , password accurately. I don't understand what the problem is? 
I have tried setting system variable it still didn't work!

Comment: While I am not familiar with what is considered on-topic there, https://cs50.stackexchange.com/ is its own community specifically for CS50 related questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have the required modules installed.

pip install psycopg2

https://pynative.com/python-postgresql-tutorial/

Comment: If you can mark the answer as correct, by clicking on the green arrow, that would be great!